# Lots of Machine Learning Models - Saving and Loading

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, persistence

Currently after training our ML models (via sci-kit) to use them at runtime, i save them as '.pkl' file and load it in memory at server startup time. My question is two folds:

1. Is there a better way of doing the same? One .pkl file reach the size of 500MBs after using highest compression. Can i save my model in some other better format?
2. How do i scale this? I have lots of such .pkl files (e.g. 20 models for different languages for one task and similarly i have 5 such tasks i.e. ~5*20 models). If i load all such .pkl files simultaneously, service will go OOM. If i load/unload each .pkl file on request basis, API becomes slow which is unacceptable. How do i scale this up or is selective loading the only possible solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What Scikit-Learn model types are you using? What is the uncompressed size of a 500MB pickle file? Inside Scikit-Learn classes there are mostly Numpy matrices. Have you checked if they are dense or sparse matrices?

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of models for which you can reduce the size without hurting performance too much, such as pruning for random forests. Other than that there is not a lot that you can do for the size of the model in-memory without changing the model itself (i.e. reducing its complexity).

I would suggest trying the joblib library instead of the pickle library, there you can use the "compress" parameter to control how strong your compression will be (with the trade off of taking longer to load).

Also note that given the type of models you use we might be able to give you better and specific advice.